# MegaCli shows "Firmware state: Failed" on new HDD

Tags: raid, lsi, megaraid

Here is the part of -PDList -a0 result:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 4
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 12
Sequence Number: 3
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 931.512 GB [0x74706db0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 931.012 GB [0x74606db0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 931.0 GB [0x74600000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Failed
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: A750
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221104000000
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data:             DT01ACA100                      MS2OA750
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No
```

I'm currently using LSI 9260-8i and it looked everything fine when I tried to setup RAID 10, but after rebooting, beeping sound started from the RAID card and MegaCli shows "Firmware state: Failed". Most weird thing is that all Error Count is zero but it failed. I updated the RAID card firmware but nothing changed.

Or is this just broken from the beginning?

Comment: Seems that some disk are not detectable by megacli .. can you try re installing it and check .. or check the disk first

Comment: I would frankly recommend asking LSI support for help, they should give it if you have an LSI branded card.

Answer (score 3):

This way you go from `Firmware state: Failed` to `Unconfigured(good)`

```
PHYSDRV=X  # set to right slot, be careful
DEVID=$(megacli -EncInfo -aALL | grep 'Device ID' | awk '{print $4}')
megacli -PdMarkMissing -PhysDrv [$DEVID:$PHYSDRV] -a $ADAPTER -NoLog
megacli -PdPrpRmv      -PhysDrv [$DEVID:$PHYSDRV] -a $ADAPTER -NoLog  # no problem if fails
megacli -PDMakeGood    -PhysDrv [$DEVID:$PHYSDRV] -a $ADAPTER -NoLog
```